# Python3 and pytest: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound:

Tags: python, jinja2, pytest

i'm creating some unit tests and i'm facing this issue

> FAILED test_views_home.py::test_index -
> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html

this is part of my testing code:

```
templates = Jinja2Templates('templates')

def test_index():
    @router.get('/', include_in_schema=False)
    async def index(request: Request):
        return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {'request': request})

    client = TestClient(router)
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert '<!DOCTYPE html>' in response.text
```

and this is my folder structure:

```
root/
├── views/
│   ├── index.py
├── templates/
│   ├── index.html
├── tests/
│   ├── test_sorullo.py
```

i got:

> FAILED test_views_home.py::test_index -
> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html

I'm guessing i'm putting wrong

```
templates = Jinja2Templates('templates')
```

but i couldn't figure it out. I didn't find anything similar searching. What i'm doing wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error says that Jinja2 template engine is unable to find the specified template file. Check your template directory and make sure the file `index.html` is present.

The template directory is set to "templates". So the Jinja2 engine will look for the templates files in the directory named "templates" in the same directory of your code file, If the template files are located in a different directory, you can specify the full path to the directory instead of just the directory name.

Try to add the full path of template directory. If it solves you can correct the directory path.